# Почему mkpasswd -m sha-512 и обычный sha512sum дают разный результат?

Tags: linux, sha

Строки самого хеша через mkpasswd -m sha-512 и через sha512sum имеют разную длину.
И нет совпадения по символам.
Через sha512sum пробовал соль и в конец и в начало добавлять, но все равно разные получаются

Comment: Потому что результат вывода mkpasswd содержит в себе нехэшированную соль, несколько тысяч итераций хэширования и формат вывода base64 — ничего этого в sha512sum нет

Comment: про формат знаю, про base64 и несколько тысяч итераций не знал, спасибо за информацию